# Yii multiple relations between different models in different modules

Tags: php, yii

How would i add a 3rd relation to my relations() function to join the `CommentsPosts` model with the `store` model. Where `CommentsPosts.store_id = Store.id` and `CommentsPosts.store_zip = Store.zip`?

in my comment.php

```
  public function relations()
        {
            return array(
                'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, $this->module->userModelClass, 'userId'),
                'posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, "CommentsPosts", array("commentId" => "id")),
                'store'=>'',

            );
        }
```

CommentsPost.php is in `modules/comments/model` and Store.php is in `modules/store/model`

FYI, i'm using Yii 1.1.15

Comment: I think you can add that relation in the store model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your relations but try something like bellow

In Comment post Model add the relation

```
 public function relations()
        {
            return array(

                'store' => array(self::HAS_MANY, "Store", array("store_id" => "id")),


            );
        }
```

When retrieving

```
   $enity->post // give all post 
   $enity->post[i]->store // gives the each post data of store
```

Comment: store is in a different `modules/model` than commentPost. is that ok?

Comment: Try it once with correct relations . I think it's not a problem

Comment: hmm, in my view. i added `print_r($data->store);` and i get this.. `Property "Comment.store" is not defined.`

Comment: Try first print_r ($data->post) if there was data try print_r ($data->post[0]->store)